# Bash, psql, how can I use wildcard when restore more pgdump files with `for` loop to more databases?

Tags: bash

Bash, psql, how can I use wildcard when restore more pgdump files with `for` loop to more databases?

Example.

```
postgres@usl-ecdt1-t:~$ cat db 
coopzilinask_shop
coopzilinask_web
ggtabakcz_shop
kitoscz_shop
kitossk_shop
metroua_shop
unihobbycz_shop
unihobbycz_web
utccz_shop
vinotekacz_shop
```

Format of file to import, with date at the end.

```
postgres@usl-ecdt1-t:~$ ls -la  /var/www/html/coopzilinask/dbdump/coopzilinask-shop-20200219094001.pgsql 
-rw-r--r-- 1 shosek ecommerce 871261032 Feb 19 09:43 /var/www/html/coopzilinask/dbdump/coopzilinask-shop-20200219094001.pgsql
postgres@usl-ecdt1-t:~$
```

Command to restore in DBs.

```
postgres@usl-ecdt1-t:~$ for i in $(cat db | grep -v "#"); do psql -U postgres -d "$i"_clone -1 -f /var/www/html/"$i"/dbdump/$i*.pgdump; done
```

But it shows me this.

```
postgres@usl-ecdt1-t:~$ for i in $(cat db | grep -v "#"); do psql -U postgres -d "$i"_clone -1 -f /var/www/html/"$i"/dbdump/$i*.pgdump; done
/var/www/html/coopzilinask_shop/dbdump/coopzilinask_shop*.pgdump: No such file or directory
/var/www/html/coopzilinask_web/dbdump/coopzilinask_web*.pgdump: No such file or directory
/var/www/html/ggtabakcz_shop/dbdump/ggtabakcz_shop*.pgdump: No such file or directory
/var/www/html/kitoscz_shop/dbdump/kitoscz_shop*.pgdump: No such file or directory
/var/www/html/kitossk_shop/dbdump/kitossk_shop*.pgdump: No such file or directory
/var/www/html/metroua_shop/dbdump/metroua_shop*.pgdump: No such file or directory
/var/www/html/unihobbycz_shop/dbdump/unihobbycz_shop*.pgdump: No such file or directory
/var/www/html/unihobbycz_web/dbdump/unihobbycz_web*.pgdump: No such file or directory
/var/www/html/utccz_shop/dbdump/utccz_shop*.pgdump: No such file or directory
/var/www/html/vinotekacz_shop/dbdump/vinotekacz_shop*.pgdump: No such file or directory
postgres@usl-ecdt1-t:~$
```

Bad wildcard. How can I apply wildcard behind name instead of date? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your files do end with suffix `.pgsql` **not** `.pgdump`:

> /var/www/html/coopzilinask/dbdump/coopzilinask-shop-20200219094001.**pgsql**

Either rename the files or try this command instead:

> ```
> for i in $(cat db | grep -v "#"); do psql -U postgres -d "$i"_clone -1 -f /var/www/html/"$i"/dbdump/$i*.pgsql; done
> ```

Comment: Thanks, repaired, tested, but still not working.

Comment: @genderbee What exactly is not working? What is the error message? Still not found? Can you provide the output of `ls -l /var/www/html/coopzilinask_shop/dbdump/coopzilinask_shop*.pgsql`